# Google Cloud TTS synthesizeLongAudio

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I'm trying to use the `TextToSpeechLongAudioSynthesizeClient` in nodejs, but am getting an error that says "Request contains an invalid argument" every time, without additional details. Does anyone have an example of how to correctly use the `TextToSpeechLongAudioSynthesizeClient`?

```js
const textToSpeech = require("@google-cloud/text-to-speech").v1;
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");
const ttsClient = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechLongAudioSynthesizeClient();

const [operation] = await ttsClient.synthesizeLongAudio({
  input: { text: "hello world" },
  voice: { languageCode: "en-US", name: "en-US-Neural2-J" },
  audioConfig: { audioEncoding: "MP3" },
});
const [response] = await operation.promise();
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
await writeFile("output.mp3", response.audioContent, "binary");
```

Comment: I've got the same problem, try with different params but no help. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of my writing, the synthesizeLongAudio requires you to have a bucket for storing created audio files. You can't expect an audio response from your code. It also requires a project id as well.

Moreover, it only accepts LINEAR16 audioEncoding, so you can't have a MP3 as an audio output either. So we need to make some changes to your code:

```js
const [operation] = await ttsClient.synthesizeLongAudio({
  input: { text: "hello world" },
  voice: { languageCode: "en-US", name: "en-US-Neural2-J" },
  audioConfig: { audioEncoding: "LINEAR16" },
  parent: 'projects/XXXXX/locations/global',
  outputGcsUri: 'gs://xxxxx-d36.appspot.com/audio/test.wav'
});
```

When you now make a request with this configuration, the wave file will be created under outputGcsUri folder. Keep in mind that a 5 minute WAV file might cost you about 15 MB. And of course, make sure you have created a bucket and gave permissions to your client.